# Unknown column 'userentity0_.last_name' in 'field list'

Tags: java, spring, web

I'm on a Java web project working with Spring Framework but have a problem when working with database (inscription, connexion).

Here is my database SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE USER (
  Login             VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  Password          VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  LastName          VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  Address           VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  Email             VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  MobilePhoneNumber INT(10)     NOT NULL,
  LoyaltyPoints     INT(4)      NOT NULL,
  PhoneNumber       INT(9),
  PRIMARY KEY (Login)
)
```

Here is my java model class:

```
package com.spring.henallux.model;

public class User {

    private String login;

    private String password;

    private String lastName;

    private String address;

    private String email;

    private int mobilePhoneNumber;

    private int loyaltyPoints;

    private int phoneNumber;

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getMobilePhoneNumber() {
        return mobilePhoneNumber;
    }

    public void setMobilePhoneNumber(int mobilePhoneNumber) {
        this.mobilePhoneNumber = mobilePhoneNumber;
    }

    public int getLoyaltyPoints() {
        return loyaltyPoints;
    }

    public void setLoyaltyPoints(int loyaltyPoints) {
        this.loyaltyPoints = loyaltyPoints;
    }

    public int getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(int phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public User() {
        this.login = new String();
        this.password = new String();
        this.lastName = new String();
        this.address = new String();
        this.email = new String();
        this.mobilePhoneNumber = 0;
        this.loyaltyPoints = 0;
    }
}
```

Here is my Entity class:

```
package com.spring.henallux.dataAccess.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Login")
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "Password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "LastName", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "Address", nullable = false)
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "Email", nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "MobilePhoneNumber", nullable = false)
    private int mobilePhoneNumber;

    @Column(name = "LoyaltyPoints", nullable = false)
    private int loyaltyPoints;

    @Column(name = "PhoneNumber", nullable = true)
    private int phoneNumber;

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getMobilePhoneNumber() {
        return mobilePhoneNumber;
    }

    public void setMobilePhoneNumber(int mobilePhoneNumber) {
        this.mobilePhoneNumber = mobilePhoneNumber;
    }

    public int getLoyaltyPoints() {
        return loyaltyPoints;
    }

    public void setLoyaltyPoints(int loyaltyPoints) {
        this.loyaltyPoints = loyaltyPoints;
    }

    public int getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(int phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    /*@OneToOne(mappedBy="user", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private CommandEntity command;*/
}
```

And here is the error message :

> 2016-12-19 11:40:35.223 ERROR 7952 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unknown column 'userentity0_.last_name' in 'field list'
>       2016-12-19 11:40:35.225  INFO 7952 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
>       2016-12-19 11:40:35.249 ERROR 7952 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/dreamsport] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
>       ...

And this message come when i try this:

```
public User save(User user){
    UserEntity userEntity = converter.userModelToUserEntity(user);
    userEntity = userRepository.save(userEntity);
    return converter.userEntityToUserModel(userEntity);
}
```

Comment: I am really sure, but why do you need to create a model an entity class separately? Can you use just the entity class?

Comment: Why did you use entity and model class together? Looks like they are doing same job

Comment: post the full stack  trace

Answer (score 0):

Just use entity class without model class and change the entity name to `User`
And dont forget to add `id` column to DB

Comment: I must use both because it's a school project and we have seen spring mvc , so we must work like this

Comment: It is kind of weird approach. Anyway, try to change entitiy class name to User and model class to like UserModel. And also post userRepository.save function

Comment: the save function in JpaRepository that  userRepository implement as an interface

Comment: It's try to set table name is userentity. Looks like implemention may be wrong

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you want to solve this problem, you have to avoid capital letters in your column name.

For example instead of:

```
@Column(name = "LastName", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
```

use

```
@Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
```